# Resource name with sub resource name in AWS HTTP end point

Tags: aws-lambda

I have gone through this [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) and created an API , mapped to my lambda function and its working fine .Now i need to add more path parameter to my URL rather than '/mydemoresource' (Eg :-/mydemoresource/sub-resource.json)  but **AWS** not allowing to give / as resource name.Any suggestion ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` is automatically setup as the root resource when setting up a new API Gateway. You can create a new method at the root level.

When published, the API Gateway includes the stage as part of the URL. In case you're referring to that, you can use [custom domain names and add an API mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) to avoid the stage name to be included in the client visible URL.